# MySql SUM and JOIN

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am trying to count sales made by a list of sales agents, this count is made every few minutes and updates a screen showing a 'sales leader board' which is updates using a Ajax call in the background.

I have one table which is created and populated every night containing the agent_id and the total sales for the week and month. I create a second, temporary table, on the fly which counts the sales for the day.

I need to combine the two tables to create a current list of sales for all agents in agent_count.

Table agent_count;

```
agent_id (varchar),
team_id (varchar),
name (varchar),
day(int),
week(int), 
month(int)
```

Table sales;

```
agent_id (varchar),
day(int)
```

I can't figure out how to combine these tables. I think I need to use a join as all agents must be returned - even if they don't appear in the agent_count table.

First I make a simple call to get the week and month totals for all agents

```
SELECT agent_id, team_id, name, week, month FROM agent_count;
```

the I create a temporary table of todays sales, and then I count the sales for each agent for the day

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_todays_sales
SELECT s.id, s.agent_id
FROM sales s 
WHERE DATEDIFF(s.uploaded, NOW()) = 0 
AND s.valid = 1;

SELECT tts.agent_id, COUNT(tts.id) as today 
FROM temp_todays_sales tts
GROUP BY tts.agent_id;
```

What is the best/easiet way to combine these to end up with a resultset such as

```
agent_id, team_id, name, day, week, month
```

where week and month also include the daily totals

thanks for any help!

Christy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  s.agent_id, ac.team_id, ac.name,
        s.`day` + COALESCE(ac.`day`, 0) AS `day`,
        s.`day` + COALESCE(ac.`week`, 0) AS `week`,
        s.`day` + COALESCE(ac.`month`, 0) AS `month`
FROM    sales s
LEFT JOIN
        agent_count ac
ON      ac.agent_id = s.agent_id
```

`team_id` and `name` will be `NULL` if there is no record in `agent_count` for an agent.

If the agents can be missing from both tables, you normally would need to make a `FULL JOIN` but since `MySQL` does not support the latter you may use its poor man's substitution:

```
SELECT  agent_id, MAX(team_id), MAX(name),
        SUM(day), SUM(week), SUM(month)
FROM    (
        SELECT  agent_id, NULL AS team_id, NULL AS name, day, day AS week, day AS month
        FROM    sales
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  *
        FROM    agent_count
        ) q
GROUP BY
        agent_id
```

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi, thats a great help. I am only getting 30 results back, I'm expecting around 120. I need also to order by the total monthly figure, so I have added the following two lines;

ORDER BY s.day + COALESCE(ac.month, 0) DESC
LIMIT 0, 150

but still a limit of 30? Is this something to do with the temp tables?

I would post my full code, with the call to build the temp tables, but I cant see how to add code tags in a reply? Or do I not need them here?

Comment: @Christy: Please post the contents of the tables (several records will be enough) and desired output of the query.

Comment: @Quassnoi - I have the system running on my local server and it is working great apart from size of the results. I have realised the problem, only agents with sales today are being shown. I need the full agent list to show. Should the join be the other way round?

Comment: @Christy: quoting your original question: *I think I need to use a join as all agents must be returned - even if they don't appear in the `agent_count` table*. Can the agents be in `sales` but not in `agent_count` and vice versa?

Comment: @Quassnoi there is definitely the case that an agent might not make a sale, but still needs to appear. There may be the case where a new agent is added into the system but will not have appeared in my nightly call to build the agent_count table - so yes, there is the case that agents could be in sales but not agent_count, and vise versa. Im really sorry if my original question was misleading or incomplete  :/

Comment: @Quassnoi thanks again. The update is pulling back all the agents now brilliant, but it appears that the sales total for each agent is now not being added to the week and month figure?

Comment: @Quassnoi: I added + SUM(day) to week and month;

SELECT agent_id, MAX(team_id), MAX(name), SUM(day), SUM(week) + SUM(day), SUM(month) + SUM(day)

and that is now working fine. You've been a brilliant help, thank you so much. Cheers

Comment: @Quassnoi: my edit was removed from the answer? Is there a better way to add the sum(day) to week and month?